# Tracking file filling syslog file with errors

Tags: 20.04

thanks for what you are doing here.  I have used the forum all the time to fix problems on my ubuntu 20.04 LTS installation.

This installation is my first, so apologies if I am missing something obvious to you guys.

I am getting a repeated error which is causing my syslog to fill quickly.  I don't notice any functionality changes in my machine, other than the syslog filling quite fast, but I haven't done anything strenuous with it in a while.  The syslog will fill until the drive is full, and then I have to start in recovery mode and remove the log file before I can get onto my desktop.

The log and some reports before it starts repeating:

```
Jul 11 16:36:22 Dragon systemd-timesyncd[857]: Initial synchronization to time server [2001:67c:1560:8003::c7]:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).
Jul 11 16:36:23 Dragon systemd[1]: blueman-mechanism.service: Succeeded.
Jul 11 16:36:24 Dragon tracker-store[1466]: OK
Jul 11 16:36:24 Dragon systemd[1282]: tracker-store.service: Succeeded.
Jul 11 16:36:25 Dragon dbus-daemon[1830]: [session uid=1000 pid=1830] Activating service name='org.gnome.gedit' requested by ':1.63' (uid=1000 pid=2480 comm="/usr/bin/nautilus --gapplication-service " label="unconfined")
Jul 11 16:36:25 Dragon dbus-daemon[1830]: [session uid=1000 pid=1830] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.gedit'
Jul 11 16:36:28 Dragon systemd[1]: fprintd.service: Succeeded.
Jul 11 16:36:29 Dragon tracker-extract[1826]: gst_queue_array_peek_nth: assertion 'idx < array->length' failed
Jul 11 16:36:29 Dragon tracker-extract[1826]: gst_buffer_get_sizes_range: assertion 'GST_IS_BUFFER (buffer)' failed
Jul 11 16:36:29 Dragon tracker-extract[1826]: gst_queue_array_peek_nth: assertion 'idx < array->length' failed
Jul 11 16:36:29 Dragon tracker-extract[1826]: gst_buffer_get_sizes_range: assertion 'GST_IS_BUFFER (buffer)' failed
```

If I kill the process tracker-extract from system monitor or terminal with kill -9 1826, the syslog file continues to fill up.

How can I find and destroy whatever is causing this problem?  I installed a good amount of stuff before I realized this was a problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: tracker reset --hard appears to have fixed the problem.  I will try a restart and make an update

Comment: This fix did not persist through a restart.  I am still looking for any insight people may have.